# iOS 13 iPad user agent problem in webview

Tags: ios, ipad, wkwebview, user-agent, ios13

I have a piece of code that had set the user agent for all of my web views:

```
   dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        {
            __block WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] configuration:[WKWebViewConfiguration new]];

            [webView evaluateJavaScript:@"navigator.userAgent" completionHandler:^(id _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                if(nil != result && [result isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
                    NSString *userAgent = result;
                    if( [userAgent rangeOfString:@"My Special User Agent"].length == 0 )
                    {
                        userAgent = [userAgent stringByAppendingString:@" My Special User Agent"];
                        NSDictionary * dictionary = @{@"UserAgent": userAgent};
                        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary];
                    }
                }

                dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(.125 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    webView = nil;
                });
            }];
        }
    });
```

However, when I tested it on an iPad Pro (12.9 inch) - 13.2.2, I found that the user agent I am getting is wrong and doesn't contain my special user agent in most cases. Interestingly enough, if I make the web view small enough (about 20% of the screen) it **does** work.

I found a workaround to set the user agent whenever I create the web view:

```
_webView.customUserAgent = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"UserAgent"];
```

Is this a safe solution (could I be losing some important information in the user agent)? 
Is there a better solution?

Comment: This probably has to do with the WKWebpagePreferences.ContentMode.

Comment: @matt do you know if it is required to set `WKWebpagePreferences.ContentMode`? What effect would this have?

Comment: Well by default the user agent and the content mode are intimately linked, and the content mode depends on the size.

Answer (score 1):

Apple removed Ipad from the userAgent in ios13 by default because

Settings -> Safari -> Request Desktop Website -> All websites. That option is enabled by default.